# Is there a way to format plotly Sankey Diagram display?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, sankey-diagram, graph-visualization

I am creating a Sankey diagram with plotly as follows:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
        valueformat = ".0f",
        valuesuffix = " %",
        orientation = "h",
        node = dict(
          pad = 20,
          thickness = 20,
          line = dict(color = "red", width = 1),
          label = ['Equity',
                   'Global Equity',
                   'Tier 1',
                   'A looooooooooong',
                   'Tier 2',
                   'B looooooooooong',
                   'C looooooooooong',
                   'Tier 3',
                   'D looooooooooong',
                   'E looooooooooong',
                   'F looooooooooong',
                   'G looooooooooong',
                   'H looooooooooong'],
          color = ['aqua',
                 'aqua',
                 'yellow',
                 'orange',
                 'yellow',
                 'orange',
                 'orange',
                 'yellow',
                 'orange',
                 'orange',
                 'orange',
                 'orange',
                 'orange'],
        ),
        link = dict(
          source = [0, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4],
          target = [1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7],
          value = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
          color = ['aqua',
                 'yellow',
                 'aqua',
                 'yellow',
                 'yellow',
                 'aqua',
                 'yellow',
                 'yellow',
                 'yellow',
                 'yellow',
                 'yellow',
                 'aqua'],
            hovertemplate='This link has total value %{value}<extra></extra>'
      ))])
    
    fig.update_layout(title_text="Waterfall Diagram", 
                      font_size=16,
                      plot_bgcolor='white',
                      paper_bgcolor='white')
    fig.show()
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way:

1. to make sure links in color aqua are always below the yellow ones? to visually separate them better - I am not sure why current set up show them in that order
2. to give more space between the links, spreading them out more? Especially I would need links and nodes not to overlap each other
3. spread out the aqua links even further? I.e. visually dissociate them from the others
4. to control where and how node labels are shown? I.e. to the right or below node, and also controlling the font for each node

Answer (score 0):

For 1, 2, & 3, you can set node locations explicitly as follows:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
    arrangement = "snap",
    node = {
        "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
        "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5], #these are fractions of the domain (0,1)
        "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
        'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
    link = {
        "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
        "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
        "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))

fig.show()
```

[Example from the plotly docs.](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#define-node-position)